# Access branches as webpage on live hosting

Tags: git, hosting, web-hosting

I'm using Bluehost to host a new website for my client, In Bluehost, I want to use Git so I can work with my coworker on the same project.

### My question

Let's say that I want to work on a file called `index.php` to add navbar, and my coworker wants to work on the same file to add a footer, How we can view my version and his version separately as webpage like `www.abc.com/dev1` to see my work or `www.abc.com/dev2` to see his?

### More explanation

I'm working on a branch called **Dev1** and my coworker works on a branch called **Dev2**, How I can view **Dev1** branch or **Dev2** branch as a webpage on a live server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the content of two different branch at the same time.
You can only work on one branch per time.

If you really need to have both file at the same time, the only possible solution is to clone again the project in a folder other than the one you are working on. In that folder switch to branch of your coworker and keep it updated every time you coworker commit&push.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a little about CI/CD you can build and upload the change from git to a webserver when a specific branch is pushed.

Ex.

When you push to dev1 it uploads to webserver to the folder /var/www/dev1 ---> [www.abc.com/dev1](http://www.abc.com/dev1)

Then when you push to dev2 it uploads to webserver to /var/www/dev2 ---> [www.abc.com/dev1](http://www.abc.com/dev1)

And when it's master merged you upload to /var/www/ ---> [www.abc.com/](http://www.abc.com/)

I think this could work.